# select sql distinct

Tags: sql

Check attached image i have more then one image corresponding to jy_id.

Result data should be:-

```
jy_id jy_tour_book_picture
70    xxxxxx.jpg
83    xxxxxx.jpg
```

using query

```
select jy_id, jy_tour_book_picture from table;
```

but this query is returning:-

```
jy_id jy_tour_book_picture
70    xxxxxx.jpg
70    xxxxxx.jpg
83    xxxxxx.jpg
83    xxxxxx.jpg
83    xxxxxx.jpg
```

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: Looks to me like either you have only 1 of each, or duplicate of almost all of them.

Comment: Cud you pls reask the question with proper details and sql code. also please remove the php tag , because I dont see any php

Comment: If there are several images for an id, you have to tell us which one to chose!

Comment: `MIN` or `ROW_NUMBER` or `DISTINCT ON`, depending on what you actully need and your DBMS supports.

Comment: sorry i"m new to this stack overflow

Comment: Don't worry. Just answer our questions! Also tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try your query like this

```
select * from images group by jy_id
```

or you can try:-

```
select distinct jy_id, jy_tour_book_picture from images
```

Comment: Accepted answer?!? These two queries are absolutely wrong. ..

Comment: #2 is the same as #1, just adding a useless DISTINCT. At least it's working in MySQL :)

Comment: yes #2 is same, my mistake. Changed now

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit or max or min or top options to get only one value

example:

```
SELECT image FROM TABLE WHERE id IN(83,84,85) limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row from the table as long as there are no other row with same jy_id that has a higher jy_tour_book_id:

```
select * from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.jy_id = t1.jy_id
                   and t2.jy_tour_book_id > t1.jy_tour_book_id)
```